# Enforcing local device placement in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a distributed Tensorflow app with a server and one or more clients using it.

Specifying which variables or ops should be placed in the server is easy. Just start a tf.train.Server with a ClusterSpec defining a 'server' job and do:

```
with tf.device('/job:server/task:0'):
  server_vars = ...
  server_ops = ...
```

However, if I want to do the same to place other vars or ops in the client side, then I'm forced to define a new job per client, start a new tf.train.Server for it, define new vars and ops placed on each specific client, and include all the client addresses and ports in the ClusterSpec.

Is there any way to use tf.device to place ops and vars locally? Not necessarily to any specific device (CPU, GPU), but not remotely in the server.

```
# No device is specified, so it's up to TF to decide where to place it.
# Let's say it decides to place it locally. How can we enforce that?
# Is there a tf.device(/local/) or similar?
client_vars = ...
client_ops = ...

with tf.Session('grpc://%s' % SERVER) as session:
  # Do stuff.
  # Can we run client ops from this session?
```

Note: I'm assuming the server works passively and never tries to access any client ops or vars directly. Rather, the clients access server ops and vars.

Comment: There's no `device/local`. You can place ops locally by using `tf.device(/job:../task:/...)` syntax since the client knows which job/task it's running on

Comment: But that forces me to start a tf.train.Server in the client and open a session to it in order to run its ops locally, doesn't it?

That's actually quite problematic to me, because for example the Tensorflow C API (for Windows use) has no support for starting servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `tf.Server` running locally, then your only option for running ops locally is to create a local session `tf.Session()` and run ops in that session. Different sessions can't communicate directly. If you are using distributed TensorFlow, you'll have to fetch data from the distributed session and feed into local session yourself. (also vica versa)